# Unable to deploy to remote ssh server in CircleCI

Tags: devops, circleci

Part of my CircleCI config is to deploy to a remote server using `scp`, now I added SSH private key (https://circleci.com/docs/add-ssh-key) and it looks like (the values masked intentionally):

[image]

And here is a snapshot of my config:

```
  deploy-web:
    working_directory: ~/subdir/web
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:16.16
    steps:
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "d7:*****fa"
      - checkout:
          path: ~/subdir
      - node/install-packages:
          pkg-manager: yarn
      - run:
          name: Build
          command: yarn build
      - run:
          name: Deploy
          command: |
            SSH_DEPLOY_PATH=/apps/my-app
            scp -r dist/* "$SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST:$SSH_DEPLOY_PATH"
```

Everything runs fine but the ssh part outputs:

```
The authenticity of host '************** (**************)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:6pix3P******M.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

Please not that i copied the fingerprint that is in the config from the web (in the screenshot). Now, is there anything am doing wrong or how do I go about it, because so far, google has not been resourceful.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this, and this is the hack (I can't believe I didn't think of this sooner), I added this step just before the `scp` step:

```
- run:
    name: Add SSH host to known
    command: ssh-keyscan -H $SSH_HOST >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Just an updated response, dont forget to add fingerprints. https://circleci.com/docs/add-ssh-key/#add-ssh-keys-to-a-job